# How to download html file with all source files in js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio

Currently I'm using this piece of code to download current page on click:

```
function Download() {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML));
  element.setAttribute('download', "file.html");
  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

Problem is that there are some audio files which are played from other server (by `<audio src>` tag). I would like to also download these files so if something will be removed on the server, saved page can still play sounds.

My idea was to replace `src` part of tag with local path and download audio files separately, but I'm wondering if there is better solution and what it would be?
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't trust the server you are getting audio files from, then downloading and provide local path is better!

Comment: I was afraid that it's the only way to do this. Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single page with any external asset contained in it directly by converting the content to [data urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). This makes the self contained HTML file easier to handle.

For example

```html
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

is a png image that doesn't require any external resource.

Comment: Thank you both, I will test it!

Answer (score 1):

Extending @6502's answer

```
<audio src="data:audio/ogg;base64,binarystring"/>
```

Convert your files to base64 string and replace `binarystring` with the produced string.

[Convert Files to Base64 string](https://www.browserling.com/tools/file-to-base64)

> Use this method wisely because it will make page load slower!
>  Bigger the
> file slower the page load!